# Calling notifyOnDataSetChanged in AsyncTask (not within the class)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

*************PROBLEM FIXED, CHECK BELOW FOR A SOLUTION*************

I have been struggling with that nearly half a day. Cannot get it work properly.
I have AsyncTask with private method, so I can pass boolean and String values in CustomLvAdapter

```
  private void changeJobStatus(final boolean isAppliedforAJob, final String jobID){
    class ChangeJobStatus extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        //private Delegates del = null;

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(isAppliedforAJob) {
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Canceling application", false);
            }
            else {
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Applying for position", false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //del.asyncCompleteOnCustomJob(true);
            loading.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            String res;
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_ID, studentID);
            params.put(Config.KEY_JOB_ID, jobID);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            if(isAppliedforAJob)
                res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_CANCEL_APPLICATION, params);
            else
                res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_APPLY_FOR_A_JOB, params);
            Log.d("Stringas", "CustomListViewBackground " + res);
            return res;
        }
    }

    ChangeJobStatus cjs = new ChangeJobStatus();
    cjs.execute();
}
```

and in onPostExcecute() I want to call notifyOnDataSetChanged() to my another activity lvAdapters.
As far as I read I have to implement delegate interface, but I didnt succeed doing that. I fail at initializing delegate in my main class, because changeJobStatus method is private and it is called in customLvAdapter class.

If I make a constructor in ChangeJobStatus class

```
      public ChangeJobStatus(Delegates delegate)
        {
             this.del = delegate;
        }
```

I have to pass something in the parameters, when excecuting it. If I pass new Delegate, my delegate implementation, which is in my another activity is not triggered.

```
 ChangeJobStatus cjs = new ChangeJobStatus(new Delegates() {
        @Override
        public void asyncCompleteOnCustomJob(boolean success) {
            //whatever
        }
    });
    cjs.execute();
```

I hope you can help me figure out right implementation for that,
Cheers

***********SOLUTION***********

Sadly, I couldn't implement what fellow user gave to me, but I am very glad that I heard from one of you I can use broadcast receiver. And it worked.
This is what I did

Create a Broadcast Receiver in your main class

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastJobList = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //what will happen, when event triggers
    }
};
```

Register custom intent and register it to Broadcast receiver in your main class onCreate method or wherever you feel comfortable :)

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction("jobListChanged");
    registerReceiver(broadcastJobList, filter);
```

All we left to do is send intent which will trigger Broadcast receiver. Following code in my scenario went to onPostExcecute method in custom adapter (context was initialized for Context at the beggining of custom adapter)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("jobListChanged");
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope I will help anyone that has this problem. Cheers!

Comment: have u tried interface?

Comment: yes, I have Delegates interface. At the moment im trying to migrate asynctask to my main class and make a call to there. But so far nullpointer received. :|

Comment: you can use broadcastreceiver in the activity in which you want to change the data of the adapter

Comment: any examples regarding that?

Answer (score 0):

// your asynctask class

```
 public class ChangeJobStatus extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        private ProgressDialog loading;
        private OnResponseListener responseListener;
        private boolean isAppliedforAJob;
        private Context con;

        public ChangeJobStatus(Context con,boolean state) {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.con=con;
            isAppliedforAJob = state;
        }

        public void setOnResponseListener(OnResponseListener onLoadMoreListener) {
            this.responseListener = onLoadMoreListener;
        }

        public interface OnResponseListener {
            public void onResponse(String responsecode);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if (isAppliedforAJob) {
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(con, "", "Canceling application", false);
            } else {
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(con, "", "Applying for position", false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            // del.asyncCompleteOnCustomJob(true);
            loading.dismiss();

            responseListener.onResponse(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

            String res="";
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.KEY_JOB_ID, param[0]);// job id
            params.put(Config.KEY_USER_ID, param[1]);// student id


            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            if (isAppliedforAJob)
                res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_CANCEL_APPLICATION, params);
            else
                res = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_APPLY_FOR_A_JOB, params);

            return res;
        }
    }
```

in your activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnResponseListener {

    String jobId="1",studId="1";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ChangeJobStatus cbs=new ChangeJobStatus(this, true);
        cbs.setOnResponseListener(this);
        cbs.execute(jobId,studId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResponse(String responsecode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //here u can do ur stuff with the string
    }
}
```